# Collapsible navigation does not work with margin - why?

Tags: html, css

I use the following code to style my navigation: [External codePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNWBdR)

```css
/*--- Navigation Main ---*/
.nav {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(200,216,239)
  
}

ul.topnav {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 450px 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: solid 1px
}

ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 70px;
}

ul.right {
  margin: auto;
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 1px
}

#club-name {
  border-bottom: 1px firebrick;
}

/*--- Navbar colors ---*/

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: rgb(144,149,158);
  color: rgb(198, 218, 238);
}


ul.topnav li a:active:not(.active) {
  background-color: rgb(46,53,66);
  color: rgb(198, 218, 238);
}


ul.topnav li a.active {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

/*--- Pseudoclasses ---*/

nav a:link {
  color: rgb(144,149,158);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: rgb(144,149,158);
}

/*--- Small Screen view ---*/
@media (max-width: 600px){
  nav {
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  ul.right,
  ul.topnav li {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

/*--- fonts ---*/
#club-name {
  font-family: Bevan;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: aliceblue
}

ul.topnav ul.right li {
  font-family: Pontano Sans;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul class="topnav">
    <li><a id="club-name" class="active" href="index.html">Hercules</a></li>
    <ul class="topnav right">
      <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Facilities</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Membership</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My styling works as I want until I set `ul.topnav { margin: 0 350px 0; }`.

If you update this `margin` to `0` and make the window smaller, you will see the effect I achieved before, but once I applied margins, the collapsible effect does not work anymore.

Hope someone can help, or offer me a different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `ul.topnav` margin to 350px, the `ul.topnav li` elements start to run into each other and wrap before the breakpoint is reached as the screen size gets smaller. You can achieve an effect similar to the one you achieved before you applied the margins by setting the margins for `ul.topnav` to `0 auto`, and then setting the `max-width` for this element to `800px` or so. This provides some space on either side of the `ul.topnav` at larger screen sizes, ensures the `ul.topnav li` elements don't get too squished at smaller screen sizes, and allows your breakpoint to work as expected.

The CSS for `ul.topnav` in this solution looks like this:

```
    ul.topnav {
        display: block;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 800px; 
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        border-bottom: solid 1px
    }
```